# How to clear the inner results of an auto suggest div when value is erased?

Tags: php, jquery

Following is my auto suggest code created using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".input_search").keyup(function() 
{
var finder = $(this).val();
var queryString = 'key_wrd='+ finder;
if(finder==''){//check if search is empty}
else
{
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "searcher.php",
 data: queryString, 
 cache: false,
 success: function(html)
 {
  $(".display_found_query_cont").fadeIn();
  $(".display_found_query-window").append(html);
 }
 });
 }return false; 
 });
 });
```

---

This code closes the suggest window and clears the enterse text

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
var search_res_container = $(".display_found_query_cont");
if (!search_res_container.is(e.target)&& search_res_container.has(e.target).length === 0)
{
 search_res_container.fadeOut().html();
 $(".search_field").val('');
}
});
```

---

what do i want to do ?

I want the results displayed to be cleared when the text entered is erased
So how do i do that?

Comment: do you want to clear the suggested result when text box is empty?

Comment: yes i want it to remain but when the box is cleared and a new result is entered the old one should dis appear and the mew result should show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
if(finder=='')
{
  //check if search is empty
  $(".display_found_query-window").html('');
}
```

As per your comment, you want to replace the old content with new result. So just chnage the below line in your ajax success.

```
$(".display_found_query-window").html(html);
```